# How to display URL outside the search box? (PHP, JS & HTML)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how do i get URL link to show outside the search box? Normally the search box display results and open up a new page with the link associated with that search result.

I don't want it to open another page when the search result is clicked, simply display the full URL (https://www.php.net..) below the search box (not inside the search results). I don't want to see contents of the target page, only the URL in the space below the search box. (Example showing part B in an image)

I think I have modified correctly for JS.

(Since PHP doesn't work on snippet I have a download link of attached php file. Stuck on Line 48 of php file)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/kkg1s4riwjyhzne/search.php?dl=0

[image]

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // Icon Click Focus
  $('div.icon').click(function() {
    $('input#search').focus();
  });

  // Live Search
  // On Search Submit and Get Results
  function search() {

    var query_value = $('input#search').val();
    $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
    if (query_value !== '') {

      $("#search-url").attr("href", "search.php?query=" + query_value);

      /* var query_value = $('input#search').val();
  $('b#search-string').text(query_value);
  if(query_value !== ''){
   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "search.php",
    data: { query: query_value },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html){
     $("ul#results").html(html);
    } 
   }); */
    }
    return false;
  }

  $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
    // Set Timeout
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

    // Set Search String
    var search_string = $(this).val();

    // Do Search
    if (search_string == '') {
      $("ul#results").fadeOut();
      $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
    } else {
      $("ul#results").fadeIn();
      $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
      $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 100));
    };
  });
});
```

```css
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 font-size: 100%;
 font: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
 font-weight: normal;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
 display: block;
}
body {
 line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
 list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
 quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after, q:before, q:after {
 content: '';
 content: none;
}
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
 border-spacing: 0;
}
a {
 outline: none;
 text-decoration: none;
}
/******************************************************************
Print Styles
******************************************************************/

@media print {
* {
 background: transparent !important;
 color: black !important;
 text-shadow: none !important;
 filter:none !important;
 -ms-filter: none !important;
}
a, a:visited {
 text-decoration: underline;
}
a[href]:after {
 content: " (" attr(href) ")";
}
abbr[title]:after {
 content: " (" attr(title) ")";
}
 .ir a:after, a[href^="javascript:"]:after, a[href^="#"]:after {
content: "";
}
pre, blockquote {
 border: 1px solid #999;
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
thead {
 display: table-header-group;
}
tr, img {
 page-break-inside: avoid;
}
img {
 max-width: 100% !important;
}
 @page {
margin: 0.5cm;
}
p, h2, h3 {
 orphans: 3;
 widows: 3;
}
h2, h3 {
 page-break-after: avoid;
}
}

/******************************************************************
Text Selection Styles
******************************************************************/

/* Safari, Chrome, iPhones, iPads */
::selection {
 background:#4096ee;
 color:#fff;
}

::-moz-selection {
 background:#4096ee;
 color:#fff;
}

::-webkit-selection {
 background:#4096ee;
 color:#fff;
}
/******************************************************************
General CSS
******************************************************************/
p {
 font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #616161;
 font-size: 10px;
}
h1 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-weight: bold;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #616161;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 20px;
}
h2 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #616161;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px
}
h3 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #616161;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 14px;
}
h4 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #616161;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 12px;
}
h5 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #ababab;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 10px;
}
h6 {
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #ababab;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 8px;
}
/******************************************************************
Main CSS
******************************************************************/
div#main {
 width: 360px;
 margin: 200px auto 20px auto;
}
.title {
 line-height: 1.2em;
 position: relative;
 margin-left: 40px;
}
div.icon {
 margin-top: 4px;
 float: left;
 width: 31px;
 height: 30px;
 background-image: url(../images/magnify.gif);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-transition-property: background-position, color;
 -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
 -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, linear;
 -moz-transition-property: background-position, color;
 -moz-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
 -ms-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
 -ms-transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
 -o-transition-property: background-position, color;
 -o-transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
 -o-transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
 transition-property: background-position, color;
 transition-duration: .2s, .1s;
 transition-timing-property: linear, linear;
}
div.icon:hover {
 background-position: 0px -30px;
 cursor: pointer;
}
input#search {
 width: 350px;
 height: 25px;
 padding: 5px;
 margin-top: 15px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
 -moz-border-radius: 2px;
 border-radius: 2px;
 outline: none;
 border: 1px solid #ababab;
 font-size: 20px;
 line-height: 25px;
 color: #ababab;
}
input#search:hover, input#search:focus {
 color: #3b3b3b;
 border: 1px solid #36a2d2;
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
 box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset, 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
h4#results-text {
 /*display: none;*/
 font-family: 'PT Sans', Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
 line-height: 1.6em;
 color: #000fff;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 16px;
}
ul#results {

 display: none;
 width: 360px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 border: none;
 -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
 -moz-border-radius: 0px;
 /*border-radius: 0px;
 -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;
 -moz-box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,.15) 0 1px 3px;
 box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, .15) 0 1px 3px;*/
}
ul#results li {
 padding: 8px;
 cursor: pointer;
 border-top: 1px solid #cdcdcd;
 transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: background-color .3s ease-in-out;
}
ul#results li:hover {
 background-color: #F7F7F7;
}
ul#results li:first-child {
 border-top: none;
}
ul#results li h3, ul#results li h4 {
 transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
 -webkit-transition: color .3s ease-in-out;
 color: #616161;
 line-height: 1.2em;
}
ul#results li:hover h3, ul#results li:hover h4  {
 color: #3b3b3b;
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Meta -->
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <title>Live Search Tutorial</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
  <!-- Load CSS -->
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Load Fonts -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=PT+Sans:regular,bold" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Load jQuery library -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Load custom js -->
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="custom.js"></script>-->

</head>

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <!-- Main Title -->
    <div class="icon"></div>
    <h1 class="title">Live Search Tutorial</h1>
    <h5 class="title">(searches through php functions and shows them on php.net)</h5>

    <!-- Main Input -->
    <input type="text" id="search" autocomplete="off">

    <!-- Show Results -->
    <!--<h4 id="results-text">Showing results for: <b id="search-string">Array</b> -->
    <a id="search-url" href="">View search results in another tab or window</a>
    </h4>
    <ul id="results"></ul>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

as i understand you have two problems

1. you want to open result in same window
2. you want to show result outside

so here my solutions

for first problem just go to your search.php file and remove target attribute

```
// Define Output HTML Formating
$html = '';
$html .= '<li class="result">';
$html .= '<a href="urlString">'; // remove target attribute from here
$html .= '<h3>nameString</h3>';
$html .= '<h4>functionString</h4>';
$html .= '</a>';
$html .= '</li>';
```

and for second problem you can create you on design and put you result in it

if don't need ul so you can customize it , you also need to change you result template in serach.php

Comment: do you mean remove $html .= '<a href="urlString">';   ?

Comment: no, in this line `$html .= '<a target="_blank" href="urlString">';` just remove  this `target="_blank"'`